# Why does setOnClickListener crashes my app?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, onclicklistener

In order to reset a user password in my app I decided to create a dialog for the user to enter their email so I could send them a mail to reset the password. The Dialog works and it looks like - [that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdPsg.png)

The code behind creating the dialog:

```
public void CreateDialogResetPassword ()
    {
        d = new Dialog(this);
        d.setContentView(R.layout.resetpassword_layout);
        d.setCancelable(true);
        btnResetPassword = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnResetPassword);
        etEmailResetPassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etResetPasswordEmail);
        d.setTitle("Reset Password");
        d.show();
    }
```

The thing is whenever I add the setOnClickListener to the btnResetPassword and then I click the Forgot Password imageButton the app crashes.

This is the code after adding the setOnClickListener method.

```
public void CreateDialogResetPassword ()
    {
        d = new Dialog(this);
        d.setContentView(R.layout.resetpassword_layout);
        d.setCancelable(true);
        btnResetPassword = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnResetPassword);
        btnResetPassword.setOnClickListener(this);
        etEmailResetPassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etResetPasswordEmail);
        d.setTitle("Reset Password");
        d.show();
    }
```

What happens after adding the setOnClickListener and then clicking on the Forgot Pasword imagebutton which should open the dialog is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNZDC.png) basically crashing the app and going to home page.

And this is how the onClick looks like -

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {



        if (v==btnLogin)
        {
            login();
        }

        if (v == btnSignUpMain) {
            CreateDialogSignUp();
        }

        if (v == imageBtnSingUp) {
            register();
        }
        if (v==imageBtnResetPassword)
        {
            CreateDialogResetPassword();
        }
```

You can ignore most of the code in the onClick I don't know how much that matters but decided to add it anyway.

Logcat -

```
2021-05-06 17:18:15.429 9175-9175/com.example.recyclub I/AssistStructure: Flattened final assist data: 1992 bytes, containing 1 windows, 12 views
2021-05-06 17:18:18.295 9175-9175/com.example.recyclub D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2021-05-06 17:18:18.296 9175-9175/com.example.recyclub E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.recyclub, PID: 9175
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.recyclub.MainActivity.CreateDialogResetPassword(MainActivity.java:143)
        at com.example.recyclub.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:207)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425)
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
2021-05-06 17:18:18.333 9175-9175/com.example.recyclub I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 9175 SIG: 9
```

Comment: please share the stacktrace from the logcat

Comment: Thank you :) I added it

Comment: did you set the onclick for your button in xml?

Comment: Its saying null object reference which means your xml button is not connected to class.

Comment: BTW: take care of java naming conventions. Method names should start with lower case character

Comment: I didn’t set the onclick in xml but in the class only. Thank you for the help so far I’ll update!

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the only problem was in this code where the Dialog is being created

```
        Button btnSubmitResetPassword = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSubmitResetPassword);
```

Needed to get reference from the dialog itself and the correct code is this -

```
        Button btnSubmitResetPassword = (Button)d.findViewById(R.id.btnSubmitResetPassword);
```

Now it is referenced in a proper way.